# Mixing UIScrollViews and UITableViews

Tags: ios, user-interface

If you look at the Featured tab of the Apple App Store app on an iPhone 6, there is a unique UI layout that I can't figure out how to replicate.

At the very top there is a navigationBar.  Below this there is a UIScrollView that animates through a number of featured items.  Below this is what appears to be a UITableView with a number of custom programmed cells.

My first guess was that the UIScrollView at the top was added to a custom cell at the top of a UITableView.  If you swipe up the UIScrollView moves with the objects below like it is a cell. You can see that the vertical scroll indicator starts at the top of the UIScrollView.

The part that is unique is that if you swipe down, the objects below the UIScrollView move down like a UITableView and the UIScrollView stays in place.  This means that the UIScrollView is not a custom cell at the top of a UITableView.

I tried making this work a number of different ways but I can replicate this.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tableview header,the header is a scrollview

- If you scroll tableview up,just use tableview default behavior,the header will scroll up.
- If you scroll down,use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to calculate the tableview header new frame,and adjust it.So it remain at top

Comment: Thanks.  Let me mess around with that for a while.  Which method is better to handle the header frame?  scrollViewDidScroll(_:) or scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_:)?

Comment: I think `scrollViewDidScroll`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you correctly, you may use UICollectionView as vertical scroll. Then, you create a custom UICollectionViewCell, each with horizontal scroll.

I haven't tried it though but done something similar to this. Hope you find a way!